# Is git cherry-pick actually the same as git show + git apply?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Could it be that

```
git cherry-pick <rev>
```

is in fact exactly the same as

```
git show <rev> | git apply -3 -
```

???

Since running either one causes exactly the same result for me and if I knew they are indeed equivalent, I could get a much better understanding of how  cherry-picking with GIT actually works, as it doesn't always give me the result I'd expect, but that's probably because the sole change cannot be applied and cherry-picking falls back to a three-way-merge (that's what `-3` does on the second command) and that would explain the unexpected result.

Comment: One obvious difference: if you changed a binary file, `git cherry-pick` will work, and `git show | git apply` will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides [Edmundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43524353/1256452), which is right and I've upvoted it, there are a bunch of other niggling details, including [ephemient's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524294/is-git-cherry-pick-actually-the-same-as-git-show-git-apply#comment74102092_43524294) about binary files (`git show` needs `--binary` to produce a binary patch) and that you may need `--full-index` as well, in some rare cases where an abbreviated `Index:` line is insufficient.<sup>1</sup>

Also, of course, `git apply` (with or without `-3`) does not mind a dirty index and work-tree, while `git cherry-pick` requires a clean index and work-tree, unless you add `-n`.  And, if you *omit* `-n`, `git cherry-pick` goes on to make a commit, which `git apply` never does.

All that said, though, yes, these two should be functionally equivalent for normal cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>To get this to occur, the blob hashes have to be non-unique upon abbreviation.  This was made automatically-correct in Git version 1.7.2, though if you force a particular abbreviation length with `core.abbrev` or a command line flag, you can still get non-unique hash abbreviations.  Adding `--full-index` ensures that you get unique ones.

(If you were to save a diff for a long period, add a bunch of *new* objects to the repository, and then try to `git apply -3` the diff, it's possible for abbreviated `Index:` lines that *were* unambiguous before to become ambiguous now.)

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, git cherry-pick works like a git merge where, instead of looking for the "best revision that is present on both branches" to check for differences and *merge* them, the "common revision" for the merging logic is forced to be the parent of the revision you are cherry-picking.

Comment: And now I'm wondering, what are the "unexpected results" you get from cherry-picking? Cause I personally find cherry-pick to be one of the best tools available in git.

Comment: Well, when I cherry-pick `rev30`, I expect to only find the changes between `rev30` and `rev29` in the result, but often I find lines that were not touched by `rev30` or `rev29` but maybe got added by `rev20`, so they are totally unrelated and still they are in the cherry-pick result, that indicates a merge failure. That is not what I expect. I expect the changes between two revs to be added and never anything that was not changed between these two revs.

Comment: Is that something that is publicly available so that we can try because if, as you said, you cherry-pick rev30, you should get changes done between rev29 and rev30 *if rev29 is the only direct parent of rev30*.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for binary files, `git apply` would not work anyway, not before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021): "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e3b9d15344fa5a09fe5c70270c9f2c2f75d0f90/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> miscounted the bytes and failed to read to the end of binary hunks.

See [commit 46d723c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46d723ce57f2dd3c50504dc6f4ca73b4c392fa6f) (09 Aug 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7e3b9d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e3b9d15344fa5a09fe5c70270c9f2c2f75d0f90), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46d723ce57f2dd3c50504dc6f4ca73b4c392fa6f): keep buffer/size pair in sync when parsing binary hunks
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Xingman Chen</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We parse through binary hunks by looping through the buffer with code like:
>
> ```
> llen = linelen(buffer, size);
>
> ...do something with the line...
>
> buffer += llen;
> size -= llen;
> ```
>
> However, before we enter the loop, there is one call that increments "buffer" but forgets to decrement "`size`".
> As a result, our "`size`" is off by the length of that line, and subsequent calls to `linelen()` may look past the end of the buffer for a newline.
>
> The fix is easy: we just need to decrement size as we do elsewhere.
>
> This bug goes all the way back to [0660626](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0660626caff6ac3745cd7b7908a2ca540141a2ec) ("binary diff: further updates.", 2006-05-05, Git v1.4.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2749fa7771f2a4323b48b78fa194a90d611bc2d8)).
> Presumably nobody noticed because it only triggers if the patch is corrupted, and even then we are often "saved" by luck.
> We use a `strbuf` to store the incoming patch, so we overallocate there, plus we add a 16-byte run of NULs as slop for memory comparisons.
> So if this happened accidentally, the common case is that we'd just read a few uninitialized bytes from the end of the strbuf before producing the expected "this patch is corrupted" error complaint.
>
> However, it is possible to carefully construct a case which reads off the end of the buffer.
> The included test does so.
> It will pass both before and after this patch when run normally, but using a tool like ASan shows that we get an out-of-bounds read before this patch, but not after.